# Knitting into a Word document in papaja

Tags: r, r-markdown, papaja

Probably a basic question but I can't see how to knit my RMarkdown document into a Word document. I've checked the various ReadMe's e.g. https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/ but can't see anywhere where it is spelled out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not knit to markdown, then use pandoc to convert to word? That is how I would do it. R studio might do this for you already, I have no idea. Not sure how familiar you are with pandoc. This should get you most of the way. https://pandoc.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to specify it in your yaml header as such:

```
---
title: TITLE
author: AUTHOR
output: word_document
---
```

Also, the [manual](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/r-markdown-components.html#rendering-options) does note that there functions won't work when converting into word.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to produce a Word document in APA style using `papaja` you can change the default output specified in the YAML front matter to the following:

```
---
output: apa6_docx
---
```

This is also [mentioned](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/r-markdown-components.html#rendering-options) in the package manual.